# Unable to conect xamarin quickblox, every time it ask require token? how i will resolve this

Tags: android, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin, I make a demo for quickblox chat, it works, but suddenly from last 5 days it does not work, every time it require Token,

And previously i download quicklox demo from developer, that was working earlier but now this is also not working, it also give error Token require.

Comment: have you contacted Quickblox for help?

Comment: i am trying but unable to contact to Quickblox